# How to scrape table which is dynamically updated

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

The table I want is in http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/hydro5d.html

I went to network tab after inspection and found request is being send in the background to 
      http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/webservice/getDailyWaterLevelListReport5.ashx?option=2

The code I used here is

```
import requests
url = 'http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/webservice/getDailyWaterLevelListReport5.ashx?option=2'
data = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(20) 
print(data.json)
```

But it is giving me no data.What could be the problem?

Comment: I went to this website https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping-cheat-sheet/ and followed Javascript Heavy Websites.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do POST, not GET:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/hydro5d.html',
}

params = (
    ('option', '2'),
)

data = {
  'DW[UtokID]': '5',
  'DW[TimeCurrent]': '11/01/2562',
  '_search': 'false',
  'nd': '1547209026513',
  'rows': '1000',
  'page': '1',
  'sidx': 'indexcount',
  'sord': 'asc'
}

url = 'http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/webservice/getDailyWaterLevelListReport5.ashx'

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
print(response.json())
```

You might need to make some values of `data` (like `'DW[TimeCurrent]'`) to be programmatically updated to get actual data every time you run your script

Comment: Thanks.@Anderson .It works.But  I want  to insert the data into pandas dataframe.Can it be done?

Comment: @HimanishBhattacharjee , I have a very little experience with pandas, so not sure if I can help you with that part of script. You might need to open new SO question